# Mongodb 2 level lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a nodejs beginner and cannot debug my problem

I have 3 models.

Cargo model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const cargoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  cargoType: { type: String, enum:['irt', 'prt', 'adr', 'pr', 'npr', 'it', 'pt', 'izt', 'hsr', 'tpd', 'zt', 'vt', 'tpv', 'st', 'pv', 'other']},
  price: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date },
  creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cargo", cargoSchema);
```

Signups model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const signupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  cargoId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cargo", required: true },
  truckId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Truck", required: true },
  approved: { type: Boolean ,required: true },
  finished: { type: Boolean ,required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Signup", signupSchema);
```

and User model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  isEmailVerified: { type: Boolean },
  registrationStep: { type: Number, enum: [0,1,2,3]},
  regDate: { type: Date },
  companyName: { type: String },
  oib: { type: String },
  telephone: { type: String },
  address: { type: String },
  city: { type: String },
  countryCode: { type: String },
  postalCode: { type: String },
  userType: { type: String, enum:['firms','drivers','both']},
  approved: { type: Boolean },
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean }
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

I want to get data from Cargos for a specific user and also get data from Cargo signups and specific user for that signup

This is my controller

```
exports.getCargosByUserId = (req, res, next) => {
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  const cargoQuery = Cargo.aggregate([
    { $match: {creator: ObjectId(req.params.id)}},
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: Load.collection.name,
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "cargoId",
      as: "loads"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: UnLoad.collection.name,
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "cargoId",
      as: "unLoads"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: Signup.collection.name,
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "cargoId",
      pipeline: [{
        $lookup: {
          from: User.collection.name,
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "signupUser"
        }
      }],
      as: "signUps"
    }
  }
]);
  cargoQuery
  .then(documents => {
    fetchedCargos = documents;
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Cargo fetched successfully!",
      cargos: fetchedCargos,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Fetching cargo failed!"
    });
  });
};
```

Nodejs doesn't print any error, so it's hard to debug, but somewhere I have made a mistake. I'm recieving cath block "Fetching cargo failed". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment you but a good help would be to print the error like this so you know more info about it:

```
.catch(error => {console.log(error)})
```